# How to create a WCF Data Services OData with with the Reflection Provider using model classes from different project?

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, wcf-data-services, odata

Following the instructions to use the Reflection Provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281.aspx) everything works well, until I move the classes Order and Item to a Class Library and reference the class library from the web project with the SVC file.

Move the POCO classes into the WCF project all goes well.

Move the POCO classes out of the WCF project into separate assembly, I get a 500 with no explanation.

I want to be able to keep my poco classes in a separate project and expose them with an OData endpoint. What am I doing wrong?

--UPDATE--
The scenario described above is meant to illustrate a problem I have found using the WCF OData Reflection Provider. It is not my real problem, but is easier to explain for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading to the latest version of WCF Data Services (currently 5.3), if you aren't already on it. I reproduced your issue using the version of WCF Data Services that ships with .Net 4.5, but once I upgraded the references in both assemblies to the latest release of Microsoft.Data.Services using NuGet, the problem went away.

If you're already using the most up-to-date version of WCF Data Services, make sure that both assemblies are referencing the exact same version of WCF Data Services.

If neither of these fix your problem, add the following attribute to your DataService class to get a more detailed error message and stack trace:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class YourService : DataService<...>
```

And then please update your question with the results of that (if the solution doesn't immediately jump out from the stack trace).

Comment: I'll give it a try today, and will let you know if it worked. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks for the tip. In moving a data entity type out of the main assembly into a common types assembly, I had to add a reference to Microsoft.Data.Services.Client to get access to the DataServiceEntity attribute and other types.  I added the .NET 4.5 version of the assembly instead of the WCF Data Services version. Woops.

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer: I usually don't like answers of the kind that don't help you with your problem but rather explain why your problem isn't the correct problem, but I think it's justified in this case :))

If you think about it, you don't really want to do that:
The Order and Item classes aren't really POCOs at all; they're *not* 'plain' C# objects; they have data attributes on them, which make them *data transfer objects* (DTOs).
They belong to the interface between your service and its clients;
The domain entities (or POCOs) Item and Order will, most likely, be a bit more complex, and contain other things besides data, such as operations and business logic.

I believe the correct way to go is to have a rich domain model, in which Order and Item contain a full set of attributes and operations, and on top of that, a DTO layer, which contains only those attributes that your service client needs.

Sending your POCOs over the wire was termed '[the stripper pattern](http://ayende.com/blog/4011/the-stripper-pattern)', and I believe it's best avoided.

Comment: Indeed this does not solve the problem. I'm not asking for guidance on patterns, I'm asking for resolution on what it appears to be a WCF limitation when using the OData Reflection Provider. And sending POCO objects is exactly what every single WebApi web service project does today, and it is NOT an anti-pattern. Thanks!

Comment: I think we have a different opinion on what POCO means. to me, it means a plain object; object with a data attribute notation isn't plain, by definition.
I'm not familiar with WebApi projects, so I can't comment on that part, just to say that if indeed this is the case, I don't agree with this technology's way of work.  
I believe that, besides revealing your internal classes to customers, sending POCOs (and by POCOs I mean domain objects) over the wire also inevitably results in sending redundant data, which, for communication operations, is of course very bad.